# Injected service is undefined in Nestjs

Tags: nestjs

I'm using GraphqQL module, I want to inject the a service to this module but it's undefined.

I'm doing like this, the service is undefined when I log it out

```
GraphQLModule.forRootAsync<ApolloDriverConfig>({
  driver: ApolloDriver,
  imports: [DataLoaderModule],
  useFactory: async (
    configService: ConfigService,
    dataLoaderService: DataLoaderService,
  ) => {
    console.log(dataLoaderService); // undefined
    return {
      debug: configService.get<boolean>('debug'),
      playground: configService.get<boolean>('graphql.playground'),
      typePaths: ['./**/*.graphql'],
      definitions: {
        path: join(
          process.cwd(),
          'src/modules/domains/graphql/generated.ts',
        ),
        outputAs: 'class',
      },
      resolvers: {
        JSON: GraphQLJSON,
      },
      context: () => {
        return {
          loaders: dataLoaderService.getLoaders(),
        };
      },
    };
  },
  inject: [ConfigService],
}),
```

This is the DataLoaderModule

```
@Module({
  imports: [PlatformModule],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [DataLoaderService],
  exports: [DataLoaderService],
})
export class DataLoaderModule {}
```

This is the startup logs when Nest Application initializes it's modules

```
[Nest] 946  - 03/23/2023, 12:34:02 PM     LOG [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
[Nest] 946  - 03/23/2023, 12:34:02 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] AppModule dependencies initialized +14ms
[Nest] 946  - 03/23/2023, 12:34:02 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] ConfigHostModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 946  - 03/23/2023, 12:34:02 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] ConfigModule dependencies initialized +0ms
undefined
[Nest] 946  - 03/23/2023, 12:34:02 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] MeilisearchModule dependencies initialized +3ms
[Nest] 946  - 03/23/2023, 12:34:02 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] StoreModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 946  - 03/23/2023, 12:34:02 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] GraphQLSchemaBuilderModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 946  - 03/23/2023, 12:34:02 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] PlatformModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 946  - 03/23/2023, 12:34:02 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] DataLoaderModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 946  - 03/23/2023, 12:34:02 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] OfferModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 946  - 03/23/2023, 12:34:02 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] GraphQLModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 946  - 03/23/2023, 12:34:02 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] ProductModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 946  - 03/23/2023, 12:34:03 PM     LOG [GraphQLModule] Mapped {/graphql, POST} route +550ms
[Nest] 946  - 03/23/2023, 12:34:03 PM     LOG [NestApplication] Nest application successfully started +1ms
```

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to put Service in `inject` parameter.
The code should be this

```
GraphQLModule.forRootAsync<ApolloDriverConfig>({
  driver: ApolloDriver,
  imports: [DataLoaderModule],
  useFactory: async (
    configService: ConfigService,
    dataLoaderService: DataLoaderService,
  ) => {
    ...
  },
  inject: [ConfigService, DataLoaderService],
}),
```